# Guess the number - Guess limits

Tags: javascript

Im making guess the number game and I'm trying to make guess limit , the player has his own guess that increases everytime he guesses till it reach maxGuesses then the player automatically lose, I've looked at many threads on how to do It but when I try to do it, the guess counter is not working properly for some reason, Here's my code

```
var hidden = document.getElementById("giveup");

hidden = document.getElementById("giveup").style.display="none";

var unhide = document.getElementById("giveup").style.display="all";

var playerGuess = document.getElementById("inputId").value

var originalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*100 + 1)





// ---------- To know the number ---------- //

// setTimeout(() => {
// alert(originalNumber)
// }, 100);

function number(){

var p3 = document.getElementById("meme")


let attempts = 0;

let maxAttempts = 10;

let playerguess = document.getElementById("inputId").value





     if(playerguess == originalNumber){

         document.getElementById("inputId").disabled = true;

         let u =  document.getElementById("demo")

u.innerText = "Congrats you won!!"

u.style.color = "green";





}else if (playerguess > 100){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "The number is less than 100"



}else if(playerguess > originalNumber){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Try a lower number"
            attempts++;

    console.log(attempts);


} else if (playerguess < originalNumber && playerguess > 0){

    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Try a higer a number"

        attempts++;

        
console.log(attempts);


} else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(playerguess) === '[object String]'){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Input a number"



} else if (playerguess < 0){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "Please make sure the number is not negative"
}
}
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">


<h1> Welcome to guessing game! </h1>

<p>Input random number from 0 to 100 </p>

  <input id="inputId" type="text" placeholder="Input here" </input>

  <button id="submit" type="button" onclick="number()">Submit</button>

  <button id="giveup" type="submit"> Give up </button>

<br></br>
  <p2 id="demo" type="text">  </p2>


<p3 id="meme" type="text"> </p2>


  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">



</head>


<body>
```

Comment: See here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-guessing-game-using-javascript

Comment: It seems you did not provide your complete code. I see an unnecessary } in your provided js code. You're using dom selectors so I assumed you have an HTML file also. If you can also provide it, it'll be easier for us to help.

Comment: You are initializing attempts variable in function number() so every time you call the function attempts is initialized to 0. I'm supposing you're calling number every time the user writes an input. If you declare it outside, it will work

Comment: It does not help, i've looked at it, It showed simple one without guess limit which what I want

Comment: You can just add a simple flag in order to limit the number of guesses. It's not that difficult!

Comment: The link I provided above gives you everything you're looking for. Just add `var maxGuesses = 3;` after `var guess = 1;` then inside function add `if (guess > maxGuesses) {alert("NO MORE GUESSES LEFT!"); return;}` That's it!

Answer (score 1):

I've put your code into VS code and the first thing my linter pointed out was an extra } at the end.
Also I can't see a break from the function if the user gets to maximum guesses.
Something like:

```
else if(attempts === maxAttempts) {
  return "You have no more guesses"
}
```

Comment: <body>
```

I call number() everytime user clicks submit when I try to console.log(attempts) it always returns 1. so comparing it to maxAttempts does nothing,  sorry about the typo.

Comment: @user16394428 In `number()` you always reset `let attempts = 0;` and `let maxAttempts = 10;`. This way they never change. You have to declare them outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using closure function

```
var round = (function () {

let attempts = 0;

let maxAttempts = 10;
    return function () {
        if(maxAttempts === attempts) {
        //end game
        console.log("No More Attempts left")
        return maxAttempts;
        }
        else {
        console.log("Yes Possible")
        return attempts++;
        }
    }
})();

round()
round();
round(); // when you reach your limit it will keep giving limit
```